# GXT 3 TreeGrid setStateful does not work

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

TreeGrid stateful option does not seem to work in GXT 3.0.1.

I do use
`setStateful(true);

 setStateId("state-id");`

But the state is not saved.
I do not use a custom StateProvider, so I expect the state to be stored in cookies, but there's nothing there.

**Update:**

I've spent some time looking at the source code and it looks like I need to create a custom StateManager to handle TreeGrid state.

Seems to be strange, because in GXT 2.2.x it is enought to call `setStateful(true)` and the component will save it's state when changed.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default, GXT initializes the StateManager with a CookieProvider. Actually many answers about StateManager can be found here http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-0-state-api
However in your particular case you have to add the state handler for reloading compoment's properties from coookies. Something like this:

```
new GridStateHandler<Row>(treeGrid, treeGrid.getStateId()).loadState();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution works, but GridStatehandler does not react on expand/collapse events in the tree grid. So, I will have to extend it.